# Javascript add onclick event on nonexistent code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm facing an issue in php/javascript. I have a table with a tons of informations and you can press many buttons for displaying many informations.

When you press this button, your web browser will display a modal and execute javascript code for querying the database. In this modal window, you have a button "delete" referencing itself... The goal is when I press the delete button, I keep the modal but the content is refresh...

You will find below some parts of my code:

The button inside the table:
`<button data-toggle="modal" href="#scommand" data-id='. $user['id'].' class="suser">display</button>'`;

The javascript: (row contains the sql answer)

```
$(document).on("click", ".suser", function (e) {
var obj = $.parseJSON(row);
$.each(obj, function(){
 <a  class="suser" onclick="delSum(sum_id)" data-id="'+ user_id+ '"'>delete</a>
}
```

The problem faced is whatever if i click or not all data are deleted...

So I tried to do this:

```
            $(document).on("click", ".suser", function (e) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(row);
    $.each(obj, function(){
    <a id="toDel+'this['sum_id'] +'" class="suser" onclick="delSum(sum_id)" data-id="'+ user_id+ '"'>delete</a>
a = document.getElementById('#toDel'+this['sum_id']);
a.on('click',delSum(this['sum_id']));
```

But it doesn't work and I get this error "a is null" I guess it's because the code doesn't exist yet...

So I don't know how to do? Any idea?

Best regards,

Comment: where is sum_id coming from

Comment: sum_id is coming from  $.each(obj, function() and contains the value of row['sum_id']

Answer (score 1):

You can write :

```
if($("#toDel'+this['sum_id']") != null)
{
    `enter onclick code here`;
}
```

Comment: Hello, in deed it seems to work now! I said seems because I got new error. When Javascript sends id information to php script i got: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "url"... I use the same function in my code, it works somewhere else but not here :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the issue, I don't know why it didn't work and I don't know why it works now. The difference is:

```
$(document).on("click", ".suser", function (e) {
var obj = $.parseJSON(row);
$.each(obj, function(){
 <a  class="suser" onclick="file(url + sum_id)" data-id="'+ user_id+ '"'>delete</a>
}
```

I call directly the function querying the php script instead of calling transitional function...

[memes](http://annabethrosen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/my-code-doesnt-work-i-have-no-idea-why.jpg)